# How to count the comparation in function strcmp() if inputs have different length?

Tags: c

I'm creating a sorting program with grade as the condition and want to know how does the strcmp() compare 2 strings with different length.For example if one of them is "A" and the other is "AB" why does the "A" is less than "AB" but if the first string is "B", the second string (which is "AB") is less than "B". How do i know the value of each string and how do i count it ?

Comment: You probably want to learn about what *lexicographic order* is.

Comment: *"How do i know the value of each string and how do i count it ?"* You can't, at least not with `strcmp`. All it says is that the return value is `0`, `<0` or `>0`, it doesn't give a meaning to the absolute value. I've seen implementations that return the difference between the values of the chars, and other implementations that only return `0`, `1` and `-1`.

Comment: re. value, it is not possible in the general case to convert a string to a "value" other than the string itself or a lossless conversion thereof and preserve the order for all strings (using the values for comparison, such as converting the strings to `int`s). For example any string consisting (only) of any number of A's is sorted before any string beginning with a B, so you already need an infinite amount of values to represent the infinite number of possible "A"-strings ("A", "AA", "AAA", …) since each distinct "A"-string has a specific position in the infinite list of all "A"-strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`strcmp` stops at the first difference.

Because `"A"` is actually two characters (`'A'` and 0), when comparing it with `"AB"`, the first difference is at the second character, and 0 is less than `'B'` in your encoding<sup>1</sup>, so `"A"` comes out as the smaller.

When comparing `"B"` with `"AB"`, the first difference is at the first character, with `"AB"` coming out smaller.

This is all rather nice, since strings are ordered as they would be in a dictionary.

---

<sup>1</sup> C pulls a fast one in this. Although 'B' is an int and may be negative, and strcmp takes const char *, 7.24.4 1 sneaks this in: “The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions memcmp, strcmp, and strncmp is determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the first pair of characters (both interpreted as unsigned char)that differ in the objects being compared.” So it is not just OP’s encoding—in any encoding, the difference (unsigned char) '\0' - (unsigned char) 'B' is negative. Except in a theoretical implementation with sizeof(int) == 1. Acknowledge [Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil).

Answer (score 4):

It's a lexicographical sort.  If one string is the prefix of another, that string comes first in the ordering.  But you can break it down like this.

You compare character by character while the characters are the same.  As soon as you reach two different characters, whichever one is smaller corresponds to the lesser string.  If one of the strings is too short to keep comparing, it is the lesser string.

Here's a basic implementation of `strcmp`.

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  while(*s1 == *s2) {
    if(*s1 == '\0') return 0;
    s1++;
    s2++;
  }
  return *s1 - *s2;
}
```

Comment: `while (*s1 && *s1 == *s2) { s1++; s2++; } return *s1 - *s2;` </codegolf> ;)

Comment: This is not quite a correct implementation. The C standard specifies the difference is computed using `unsigned char`. So the `return` statement could be `return (unsigned char) *s1 - (unsigned char) *s2;`. (Note: It does not need to return the same magnitude as this, but the sign must match.) The above could return positive for `"A"` compared to `"AB"` if the value for `'B'` is negative.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The standard says the characters are *interpreted* as `unsigned char` which isn't necessarily the same thing as *converted* to `unsigned char`. Perhaps it converts the pointers to `const unsigned char *`.